# How are deciles defined when you have very few records to compute it?

Tags: deciles

How are deciles defined when you have very few records to compute it?

For ex: ntile(10) as defined by standard frameworks, over, say, [1,2,3,4] gives us [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)]

Comment: This isn't, perchance, because you are trying to implement the Hosmer-Lemeshow test, is it?

Comment: The [Hyndeman and Fan](https://www.amherst.edu/media/view/129116/original/Sample+Quantiles.pdf) paper gives a theoretical/historical overview of the 9 methods that Peter alludes to.

Comment: I don't understand how this is unclear at all.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I'd say that deciles are silly if you have N < about 40 and utterly silly if N < 10. `R` offers 9 different variations of quantiles and deciles gives different results with different types for (1,2,3,4).  E.g. for type 1 it gives:

```
1   1   2   2   2   3   3   4   4
```

but for type 3 it gives

```
 1   1   1   2   2   2   3   3   4
```

is the third decile of this 1 or 2? Who knows? Who cares? Why ask?  It's a case where taking deciles gives *less* information with *more* numbers!